# I created a framework using xcode6 but can't able to access it

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to create  asimple framework for testing.

I referred this [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khY41.png) and step by step do every one.

But, when I Build the program , It is always show the error "**File not found**".

I have used Aggregate Target to build the framework, like the website explain.

it is my framework project file code(header file).

[image]

it is my framework project file code(implement file).

[image]

it is my framework setting photo.

[image]
it is my test to use the framework file code.
[image]

it is my test to use the framework project setting.
[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong in my steps?

Thank you very much.

I used XCode 6.1.1 version IDE.

//============================
@Kevin:

thanks. but..

If I change the import file. it will show error below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the ".framework" part in the import.

```
#import "MyFramework/MyFramework.h"
```

Comment: please see my edit. I have change the import file. but it will show that error. you can see my upload screenshot. thank you.

Comment: That's a completely different question. Did you add `#import "MyUtils.h"` to MyFramework.h? (might need to be "MyFramework/MyUtils.h" instead).

Comment: Thank you , @Keven. I have not add MyUtils.h to MyFramework.h. So It will not found the method. When I add import file. It will show correct. Thank you very much,@Keven .  :)