# Can't find the swift file in framework header

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to create asimple framework for testing with swift.

I had post the question in objective-c with "create the framework" [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652648/i-created-a-framework-using-xcode6-but-cant-able-to-access-it/27653028#27653028). It was resolved.

But I'm trying to create framework with swift.

I encounter the problem. I can't import the MyUtility file in header file.

like below:

[image]
[image]

Have anyone know how to import the file in my custom framework?

thank you very much.

============== edit ===========

for @Jerome L

[image]

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823542/cant-access-swift-class-from-custom-dynamic-framework-swift

Answer (score 10):

In order to import Swift in objective C, you need to use the following syntax:

```
#import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
```

So I guess in your case ti would be something like:

```
#import <MyFramewordSwift/MyUtility-Swift.h>
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: Thank you @Jerome L, But I change to #import <MyFrameworkSwift/MyUtility-Swift.h> , It is show file not found.@@

Comment: According to apple documentation you should first: "Under Build Settings, in Packaging, make sure the Defines Module setting for that framework target is set to Yes.". Sorry, I don't have xcode right now to test. You can still follow the link I putin my answer. It will explain in detail how to do the import. Thanks

Comment: I had set defines module to yes, I had post the build settings in my article edit part, you can refer the photo. I don't know where the problem in my project or code. Thank you very much.

Comment: this is different case, what you are talking about is importing a swift file into an objective-c file, and that relies on taking the module that the swift file is in and importing that into the .m file.  The question here is how to import a swift file into a framework header

Comment: The import format is the correct answer. I wish I could give you a million upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue.  I have an all swift project and am making a pure swift framework.  In order to get the target in the same project file to see the classes in my framework, I needed to explicitly add the modifier
`public` in front of my class declaration and in front of any method that I wanted to be accessible.  Here is an example of one of the classes.

```
private let _sharedInstance = SomeManager()

public class SomeManager: NSObject {
    
    //MARK: - Singleton instance
    
    public class var sharedManager : SomeManager {
        return _sharedInstance
    }

     public func outwardFacingMethod()-> Void {
        internalMethod()
    }
    
    private func internalMethod()-> Void {

    }
   
}
```

The documentation in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) states here but is a bit buried.  If you scroll down to the section called **Importing Code from Within the Same Framework Target** it says

> Because the generated header for a framework target is part of the
> framework’s public interface, only declarations marked with the public
> modifier appears in the generated header for a framework target.